# Zoom in where the focus is

Tags: software-recommendation, video, screen-capture

I use Mac. When I do a presentation or make a screen recording, sometimes I need to zoom in to the part where the focus is; then I need to zoom out to restore the normal screen size.

I have seen people doing this, but I don't know how they achieved that by keyboard and mouse.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I know that we could post-process videos. But I have seen people doing this during presentation, so I think they achieved that in real-time by keyboard and mouse, that's what I want.

Comment: That’s great details to add to the question body (hint, hint)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with accessibility features that are baked into macOS. They're located under System Preferences -> Accessibility. You can change the keyboard shortcuts under System Preferences -> Keyboard.

There are a couple different settings for the zoom type. It sounds like you might want to try fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by holding the `CTRL`-key and `scroll` up (zoom in) or down (zoom out).

You may have to enable the setting first. The setting is called "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom:". You can find it under `System Settings` -> `Accessibility` -> `Zoom`.

Make sure `Zoom style` is set to `Full screen`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have pinch to zoom enabled in your trackpad settings, couldn't you pinch in and out on the trackpad in order to zoom in and out?